# Perfom an action in viewDidAppear only when view is first displayed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an app that has a view that contains 4 circles made with UIBezierPath.

[image: view with circles]

And you can click on a certain circle to get details about one of the items

[image: view with details]

The thing is, Circles are in subviews that have some constraints, so I could not draw them in the viewDidLoad method (I tried but it was a mess) so the whole drawing thing is done in the viewDidAppear method but that makes the circles to be drawn each time the view appear.

So if I click on a circle then come back to the circles view a lot of time I end up with :

[image: view with circles after I went to check the details a lot for any circle]

I also tried to use the viewDidLayoutSubviews method but I get an infinite loop. So I'm asking if anyone has an idea to deal with that. (with the cleanest way possible)

This is what my viewDidAppear looks like :

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        createCircle(firstCircle, text: "Breathe", color: blue, directionForAdjustment: 1, identifier: 0)
        createCircle(secondCircle, text: "Cocoon", color: green, directionForAdjustment: 1, identifier: 1)
        createCircle(thirdCircle, text: "Smokeless", color: cyan, directionForAdjustment: -1, identifier: 2)
        createCircle(fourthCircle, text: "Sleep", color: purple, directionForAdjustment: -1, identifier: 3)
}
```

Comment: Just add a Flag in it

Comment: your circle value change after init circle?
after does not any changes that you are write code viewdidload method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this code to execute only the first time when the view appears, just add a boolean variable that says "is initialized". If not run the code in viewDidAppear then set it to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can override and add UI customization in [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) , the subviews bound after `super viewDidLayoutSubviews` are correct on screen and it will not be executed each time the view appears.

Edit:
The problem with infinite loop might be that you call `setNeedsLayout` in your `createCircle` method. I think you should reconsider `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and your `createCircle` logic, since it should be the optimal flow that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `dispatch_once`:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {
    static var once: dispatch_once_t = 0

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        _dispatch_once(&YourClass.once) {
            self.viewDidAppearFirstTime()
        }    
    }

    func viewDidAppearFirstTime() {
         createCircle(firstCircle, text: "Breathe", color: blue, directionForAdjustment: 1, identifier: 0)
         createCircle(secondCircle, text: "Cocoon", color: green, directionForAdjustment: 1, identifier: 1)
         createCircle(thirdCircle, text: "Smokeless", color: cyan, directionForAdjustment: -1, identifier: 2)
         createCircle(fourthCircle, text: "Sleep", color: purple, directionForAdjustment: -1, identifier: 3)
    }
}
```